# How to change the behavior of semicolon in the jQuery-tags-input plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tags-input

I am using the jQuery-Tags-Input plugin : [Github page](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) /  [Demo](http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/).

You can notice with the demo that when you press `enter` **as well as `,`**, the current tag is submitted. I would like the same when you press `;`. By default, when you press `;`, it is considered part of the tag.

I could not find this in the options. Is there another way than tweaking the code directly ? Has someone done it already ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the *delimiter* parameter, but it looks like you can only pass it one character, not an array.

You could always just hard code it into line 294. Change this:

```
if (event.which==event.data.delimiter.charCodeAt(0) || event.which==13 )
```

To this:

```
if (event.which==event.data.delimiter.charCodeAt(0) || event.which==59 || event.which==13 )
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kbwqr/